# Data wrangling: Convert long format of sequences to wide format of specific subsequences

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr, sequence, tidyr

I am studying state changes for multiple subject sessions. My original dataset was formatted long, with a separate row for each state for each session. Something like:

```
Session StateCount  State
1       0           B
1       1           C
1       2           B
1       3           B
1       4           A
…       …           …
56      26          A
56      27          B
```

Using the `tidyR` `spread` function in R...

```
d0_Spread <- spread(d0, key = "StateCount", value = "State")
```

...I was able to convert the data to a wide format (1 row per session, 1 column per state in the session), which was needed for some sequence-based calculations:

```
Session 0   1   2   3   4   …   [Nth State of Longest Session]
1       B   C   B   B   A   …                NA
…       …   …   …   …   …   …                …
56      A   C   B   C   C   …                NA
```

I now want to run the same calculations on two different types of ***subsequences*** within a given session (rather than across an entire session). However, I'm having difficulty wrangling the required data into wide format.

Below is the `dput()` output for a representative sample of the new long-format dataset:

```
structure(list(Session = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L, 56L
), StateCount = c(0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
11L, 12L, 13L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L), State = structure(c(2L, 
3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C"), class = "factor"), 
    State_AType = structure(c(5L, 6L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 
    2L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 6L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 1L, 5L
    ), .Label = c("A", "A_L", "A_S", "A4", "B", "C"), class = "factor"), 
    State_AType_629Num = structure(c(9L, 10L, 9L, 3L, 9L, 4L, 
    9L, 9L, 1L, 9L, 5L, 9L, 10L, 6L, 7L, 9L, 10L, 2L, 9L, 1L, 
    9L, 8L, 9L), .Label = c("A_L", "A_S", "A1", "A2", "A3", "A4", 
    "A628", "A629", "B", "C"), class = "factor"), StateDuration = c(1L, 
    1L, 37L, 147L, 32L, 42L, 24L, 2L, 8L, 1L, 17L, 8L, 8L, 2L, 
    297L, 1L, 11L, 73L, 27L, 28L, 46L, 14L, 127L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-23L))
```

It, like the first dataset, has a row for each state within each session. It contains the same data columns as my first dataset (e.g., `Session`, `StateCount`, `State`), but also a few additional columns:

- In addition to `State` (which codes each state as either "A", "B", or "C"), there is `State_AType`, which differentiates between a normal "A" (of which there are 629) and two alternative A types ("A_S" and "A_L"), a distinction that matters below.
- The `State_AType_629Num` is a repeat column, but it provides a unique identifier for the 629 normal "A" states (e.g., A1, A2...A629), in case helpful for the below.
- The `State_Duration` column captures the time duration of the state (needed for the below).

Using this dataset, I now need to create the following wide formats for the intended subsequence analyses:

**1) First state to each normal "A" state** - a wide format in which each row represents a sequence from the first state of a session to each "A" state of the session. There would be 629 such rows (one for each *normal "A" only*; that is, **not** for "A_S" or "A_L" states). Each column value would be a state within the sequence. Complicating things a bit further, I'd also like to calculate the total duration of the sequence. This means the `StateDuration` variable would also need to be accounted for, so that each row of the output notes the sum of `StateDuration` for all of the states in that sequence.  For the sample data provided above, the desired data frame would be structured as follows, producing the listed values:

```
SeqEndpnt      0    1   2   3   4   5   …   [Nth State of Longest Sequence] SumDuration
A1             B    C   B   NA  NA  NA  …                NA                     39
A2             B    C   B   A   B   A   …                NA                     218
A3             B    C   B   A   B   A   …                NA                     295
A4             B    C   B   A   B   A   …                NA                     328

…              …    …   …   …   …   …   …                …                      …
A628           NA   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  …                NA                     NA
A629           A    B   C   A_S B   A_L …                NA                     483
```

**2) Previous "A" or "A_L" state to next "A" state** - a wide format in which each row represents a sequence from the previous "A" or "A_L" (whichever was more recent) to the next normal "A" (importantly, an "A_L" state could begin a sequence but cannot terminate it). As above, there would be 629 such rows, with the columns again representing a state in the sequence.  The first sequence within a given session would likely be blank, as there would be no "A" previous to the first "A"; the exception would be if there were an "A_L" that preceded the first "A". For the sample data provided above, the desired data frame would be structured as follows, producing the listed values:

```
SeqEndpnt       0   1   2   3   4   5   …   [Nth State of Longest Sequence] SumDuration
A1              NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  …                NA                     NA
A2              B   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  …                NA                     32
A3              B   B   A_L B   NA  NA  …                NA                     35
A4              B   C   NA  NA  NA  NA  …                NA                     16
…               …   …   …   …   …   …   …                …                      …
A628            NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  …                NA                     NA
A629            B   C   A_S B   A_L B   …                NA                     186
```

I assume the solution this time will require a combination of the `spread` function used earlier with some `for` loops.  However, I'm not especially experienced with the latter, particularly in the context of iteratively adding values to a data frame. Alternatively, I thought `reshape2`, `group_by`, or `mutate` may assist with achieving the desired sets, but am not familiar.

Any help would be extremely appreciated!

Comment: See [mcve] and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). There's a lot of text here, but not a whole lot of code or data (very preferable for data to be included in the post, instead of downloaded from a third-party site that we may or may not trust).

Comment: Actually, long format is the preferred format in nearly any analytical method. Wide is usually for reporting. Please explain the *subsequence analyses*. Couldn't a regular filter/subset work?

Comment: Thanks, @camille . I'm wasn't sure what additional code to include as I don't yet have an approach (see last paragraph).  As for data, I've added examples of subsets of these rather long data frames (thousands of rows in long format, 500+ columns in wide format).  As such, `dput()` didn't seem like the way to go, but if there's another suggested means of sharing more, please let me know.

Comment: Thanks, @Parfait . I've updated the post to show the desired wide format.  This formatting, to my knowledge, is what is required for use with the [TraMineR package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/TraMineR/index.html) for analyzing the sequences.

Comment: You can call `dput` on a representative sample of data, as suggested in the second link I posted

Comment: Thanks, @camille I have replaced the in-text subset with the `dput()` output of a fictitious sample. This sample includes the different edge cases that I noted need to be covered by solutions for the two desired sequencings. Additionally, the in-text tables at the end of the post (one for each sequencing) now correspond with the new sample - that is, working solutions employing the `dput()` output should produce data frames with the same values presented here. Finally, I have removed links to the original data files, so that all needed information is provided within the post. Thanks again.

Comment: @camille Thanks again.  With the example now in place, any thoughts on an approach?